# Highlight code in comment field

Tags: support

I want to highlight the code in comment box, How can do this. I want to highlight my syntax code highlight in comment field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Martijn Pieters said

> If the code is part of an answer, make it an answer. If the code is to
>   clarify a question, edit the question to include the code.

But still, if you want to add code snippet in comment(minor if some other user need clarification.. and doesn't add much to question ), then you can try adding your code in  backticks block **(`)** ... like this

`System.out.println("str")`

Comment: Like this `System.out.println("str")`

Comment: Code in comments is not highlighted, even when written between back ticks. Then, that is the behavior of inline code even with questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Comments are not full-fledged posts, they do not support multiple lines and certainly do not support syntax highlighting.

At best, you can mark text with backticks to be rendered in a typeface font: `` `typeface font` ``

If the code is part of an answer, make it an answer. If the code is to clarify a question, edit the question to include the code.

Comment: thats cool, so y -vote??? i have seen some one commneted me with highlighted code

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316899/combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients-in-ie

Comment: Here you can see the commnets got highlighted. is't it?????

Comment: @DineshKanivu - you can make the code have the grey background with backticks (\`) `like this` but you can't get syntax highlighting more than that.

Comment: @John Palmer Thats only my question. and its possible as u say. Then what is mean by highlighting i mean??? i mean thta only

Comment: @DineshKanivu - syntax highlighting is certain words in different colors - the different colors for language keywords - for example in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327506/call-an-f-ticked-function-name-with-embedded-spaces-xxx-yy-from-c-sharp

Comment: @DineshKanivu: That is not highlighting; there is no color coding of keywords. That is displaying selected text as `teletyped`; use backticks for that.

Comment: i am not talking about, i am talking about commnet

Comment: @DineshKanivu: You are using the term *highlighting* and John is merely showing you what *we* understand highlighting to mean. Syntax highlighting is only possible in full-fledged posts. What you are talking about is not highlighting.

Comment: Ok leave, all of you guys notice this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316899/combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients-in-ie. ok See one of the commnets highlighted its background  in grey color. Just tell me how can i do that, instead of showing interest to give -ve vote

Comment: @DineshKanivu - Are you talking about [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316899/combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients-in-ie#comment28611454_19317176)?

Comment: @DineshKanivu add you text in between two back ticks **`** as I have answered.. that part will be in  grey color indicating code formatting...

Comment: @hims056  Yes sir

Comment: @DineshKanivu: We already told you how to do that; use backticks. Different sites will render such text in different ways. Stack Overflow uses a grey background, here on Meta the background colour is white but the font does change: `example text in backticks`.

Comment: @DineshKanivu - Have a look at [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for how to format comments